# Is it guaranteed that load event on a <script> tag is always fired immediately the script is executed?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Suppose there are two JavaScript files.

one.js

```
window.a=1;
```

two.js

```
window.a=2;
```

And the loader:
loader.html

```
<body></body>
<script>
const s1=document.createElement("script");
s1.src="one.js";
s1.addEventListener("load",()=>console.log("one.js",window.a));
const s2=document.createElement("script");
s2.src="two.js";
s2.addEventListener("load",()=>console.log("two.js",window.a));
document.body.appendChild(s1);
document.body.appendChild(s2);
</script>
```

Does it always produce as [Out-1] or [Out-2]? (Edited: It means neither "I want the code which always produces [Out-1]" nor "I want the code which always produces [Out-2]". Both [Out-1] and [Out-2] are acceptable.)

[Out-1](Run in order of s1-exec-> s1-onload -> s2-exec -> s2-onload. It is OK):

```
"one.js" 1
"two.js" 2
```

[Out-2](s2-exec-> s2-onload -> s1-exec -> s1-onload. It is OK, too):

```
"two.js" 2
"one.js" 1
```

What I am worrying is whether the browser may run in order of s1-exec -> s2-exec -> s1-onload -> s2-onload and produce as [Out-3]

[Out-3](Not OK):

```
"one.js" 2
"two.js" 2
```

I checked HTML5 specification
https://www.w3.org/TR/2008/WD-html5-20080610/tabular.html#script

ant it says:

> If the load was successful
>
> 1. If the script element's Document is the active document in its browsing context, the user agent must execute the script:
>      ....
> 2. Then, the user agent must fire a load event at the script element.

Does it guarantee that "Other script tags never interrupt the process between step 1 and step 2"?.

(edited) On the other words, I am wondering about whether the HTML specification requires the browser to run step1 thru step2 synchronously(The title "immediately" means this).

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/load looks like the answer is a no. The load event is fired when it finishes loading. The next question is, is the line of code synchronous? I doubt it since it is an event listener... trying to find that hence I'm not leaving an answer.. (yet). great question btw.

Comment: Thank you for your information. At least, the specification above seems to guarantee on"load" is fired after "execution" (It never happens before execution is finishied). But it does not say that the entire process should be synchronous.

Answer (score 0):

Per specs at least, yes it is guaranteed that the load event *fires* at the end of the ["execute the script block"](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/scripting.html#execute-the-script-block) algorithm.

So, you can face [out-1] and [out-2], but not [out-3].

When you do append a <script> element in the document it will get loaded as an `async` script.
This means that the order of execution between script-1 and script-2 can't be guaranteed.

```js
// scr1 will load an external script
const scr1 = document.createElement('script');
scr1.onload = e => console.log('1', window.$);
scr1.src = 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/jquery/jquery@3.2/dist/jquery.js?' + Math.random();
// scr2 will load a dataURL script
const scr2 = document.createElement('script');
scr2.onload = e => console.log('2', window.$);
scr2.src = 'data:application/javascript,$="script 2"';

// even though scr1 is appended first
document.head.appendChild(scr1);
document.head.appendChild(scr2);
```

However when they do ask to [fire](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#concept-event-fire) the event at the end of the *execute the script block* algorithm, there is no place for any race condition, the event's callbacks will get executed synchronously.

(note: If they were asking to "[queue a task](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#queue-a-task) to [fire an event](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#concept-event-fire)", like they do in other places, then the callbacks would have fired asynchronously, but still no race conditions since both tasks would get queued on the same task queue).

Comment: My view is that the non-interleaving of the steps is enforced by the [list of scripts that will execute in order as soon as possible](https://w3c.github.io/html/semantics-scripting.html#list-of-scripts-that-will-execute-in-order-as-soon-as-possible) to which the successfully fetched scripts are added. Since the execution of the script is driven by processing the scripts on that list, they can never interleave. Note however the distinction between classic and module scripts. The load event is fired immediately after running a classic script, but a task is queued to fire the event on a module.

Comment: @Alohci, yes that's how I read this too, my concern is more about when the event callback will get executed. I am not sure if [event fires => event callbacks execution] is always synchronous. One could delay the execution of the callback to the next frame, and their could be a case where the next "script to execute as soon as possible" is executed right after the first event fired, but before the callbacks are handled. Though I'm really not sure about this scenario, and trying to force it never results in [out-3].